# HTML Page issue

Tags: html

I just made a html page with this code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>RLGaming</title>
<style  type="text/css">
body {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #000000;
    width: 1600px; 
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 20px;
    /*border: 1px solid black;*/


}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<img src="test/SplashPageFinished.png" alt="" width="1600" height="1400" usemap="#Map" style=""/>
<map name="Map">
  <area shape="rect" coords="333,447,596,907" href=>
  <area shape="rect" coords="673,447,938,908" href=>
  <area shape="rect" coords="1002,446,1267,907" href=>
  <area shape="rect" coords="752,1019,801,1039" href=>
  <area shape="rect" coords="487,60,1092,355" href=>
</map>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that when i am running this html file locally on my pc it gets centered on the screen. However when i upload it to my webhosting and load it its no longer centered on the screen. How to make it centered ?
Webpage is : http://rlgaming-wow.co.uk

Comment: Try using ctrl-f5 in both tests.

Comment: can you post a link to your page?

Comment: put <center><map name="Map"> ..... </map> </center>

Answer (score 1):

Give a try on flex boxes! It's really easy to center thing :)

```
#wrapper{

    display: -webkit-box;      /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
    display: -moz-box;         /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
    display: -webkit-flex;     /* NEW - Chrome */
    display: -ms-flexbox;      /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
    display: flex; 

    justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
}
```

Comment: I am not running a css. All is in the html file nothing to do with css.

Comment: Did you removed the body's style?

Answer (score 0):

Use your wrapper ID as main container and give width to it and then apply auto margin.

**Code**

```
#Wrapper{
width: 1600px; 
margin: 0px auto;
padding: 20px;
}
```

I think you must also try reset css in your page that can help you.

Every browser has its own default ‘user agent’ stylesheet. The goal of a reset stylesheet is to reduce browser inconsistencies in things like default line heights, margins and font sizes of headings, and so on.

**Reset CSS:**

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Comment: I am not running a css. All is in the html file nothing to do with css.

Comment: what that mean 'not running a CSS'. for presentation of page you need to use CSS.

Comment: Its just running on this simple index.html file.

Comment: you can add css in head, no need to add extra css file.

Comment: I got a css script in head  text-align: center;
    background-color: #000000;
    width: 1600px; 
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 20px;

Comment: A better approach though is to have an inner container div, which will be centralized, and not the body